# How to evaluate Jmeter Aggregare Report Results?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to conduct a performance test on my targeted web application. For this reason, as I search through, I realized I needed to use JMeter for this purpose. I had a test and used aggregate report which is as follows:

[image]

What I wonder is that Error rates are so high... I couldn't identify the problems. What would be the inference that I can insight from this result? The thread properties are as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate Report doesn't tell the full story, you might want to use [Response Code Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/) listener in combination with [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/), both can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager). Alternatively you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), in this case you won't have to install these plugins

Given very small "min" response times and very high "max" response times I can assume that your application doesn't handle that amount of users very well, you might want to increase the duration of your test and ramp-up period in order to see where is the first [bottleneck](https://qa-platforms.com/detecting-bottlenecks-performance-testing/), I can think of the following stages:

1. User number increases, throughput increases, response time remains the same (low)
2. User number increases, throughput stays the same, response time starts increasing - this is the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html)
3. User number increases, throughput decreases, response time increases - performance bottleneck

Once you have the numbers you will be able to report them.